# Uncaught (in promise) Error: Incorrect argument types for tabs.discard

Tags: javascript, vue.js, browser-extension

As the title, I always get this error in console when I debug my extension in firefox, I'm using polyfill and vuejs to have a cross browser compatible extension. This is the code:

functions.js

```
const discardInactiveTabs = () => {
  browser.tabs.query({active: false, highlighted: false}).then( (tabs) => {
    tabs.forEach( (tab) => {
      if( !tab.active && !tab.discarded ){
        browser.tabs.discard(tab.id);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

And this is how I call the discard fuction in my background.js file:

```
browser.tabs.onCreated.addListener( (tab) => {
  discardInactiveTabs();
  initTab();
});

browser.tabs.onUpdated.addListener( (tabId, changeInfo, tab) => {
  if( tab.url === 'chrome://newtab/' && changeInfo.status === 'complete'){
    discardInactiveTabs();
    initTab();
  }
});
```

Any suggestion?